# Twig reports "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, twig

I am getting this error in Laravel:

> Twig \ Error \ RuntimeError An exception has been thrown during the
>   rendering of a template ("Route [shortname.shortname_list] not
>   defined.") in "common.sidebar.vendor.twig" at line 154.

I already checked my sidebar.twig, route list and controller, it seems like fine.

What does this error mean, and what is a possible solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error means that a route with the name `shortname.shortname_list` isn't defined in your route configuration.

You need to ensure that you have a route with the name `shortname.shortname_list` to be able to generate a URL for it in twig.

```php
Route::get('route-path', ['uses' => 'Controller@method'])
    ->name('shortname.shortname_list');
```

Comment: I have that already in my route list, i'm just wondering why that still happens even i declared it on my web.php file.                                    
`Route::get('catalog/plan/price/list', 'ShortnamesController@shortname_list')->name('shortname.shortname_list');`

Comment: Is it inside a route group? Can you check the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Yes it's inside the route list. 
(https://dochub.com/bricxcarasco-gss/p7e92j/screenshot-from-2019-07-31-11-49-14-png?dt=3dtgs97FWsgHJ8Sh4dsB)